# Download video from AmazonS3 with ProgressBar in Android

Tags: android

Here i developed one application which download big size of videos from `AmazonS3Bundle` with `HorizontalProgressBar` but when i go to home screen by pressing home key and when i get back to my application's download screen, my download is restarting from beggining.

I want  my application to keep downloading in background even if  i go to any other application.

Comment: ...that's nice but this isn't really a question, do you expect people to magically guess your code and fix the issue for you?

Comment: Is there any problem with this Question, please explain why giving me minus ranking ?

Comment: You should upload your code with question, that's what Mat is asking

Comment: Quite. No code, you somewhat say what the problem looks like but nothing technical, you don't say what you have tried and what hasn't worked. Basically you did nothing that you are asked to do before asking a question.

Comment: Please ask the your questions precisely so that anyone can understand by reading only once. If you ask the question which is very hard to understand people will vote down your questions.

Comment: That's because your Activity's onCreate() gets called everytime, You should make one `Service` class to do the download task, So it will keep doing it in Background irrespect of the state of the Application. Search for the example with Service to download.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your Activity's onCreate() gets called everytime and the task to Download gets started again.

You should make one `Service` class to do the download task, So it will keep doing it in Background irrespect of the state of the Application.

Check these two examples : [**first**](http://android-ed.blogspot.in/2011/04/creating-and-using-service.html) and [**second**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/FileDownloadService.htm) link